# Mac OS Sierra keeps logging out when I do full screen

Tags: macos-sierra

Since updating to Sierra, when I hit full screen on Excel, I am logged out. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a [known issue](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7678232?start=90&tstart=0) that affects all apps, so hopefully it will be fixed in an update.

In my case, I needed to go to full screen to see the tabs at bottom of the window. It also happened if I hit the green resize button. However, if I hit `Windows/Zoom Window`, the tabs appear.